# Proofing this math pattern

Tags: education, solution-verification

I have this proof/pattern I am trying to solve:

2 + 3 = 8

3 + 7 = 27

4 + 5 = 32

5 + 8 = 60

6 + 7 = 72

7 + 8 = ?

I have to find what the question (?) represents, until now I have tried a few approaches but they are coming up with different answers, is there a fixed solution to this, if so, what is the most logical way using a proof? Appreciate all the insights for this problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one wasn't too bad:

Notice: $$2 \times (3+1) = 8$$
$$3 \times (7+2) = 27 $$
$$4 \times (5+3) = 32$$
$$5 \times (8+4) = 60$$
$$6 \times (7+5) = 72$$

noticing that the second factor is $b+(a-1)$, we deduce that

$$7 \times (8+6) = 98$$.

The pattern is $a + b = a \times (b+a-1)$.

Comment: My first thought was 2x4, 3x7, 4x8, 5x12, 6x12, but i need a way to relate them to 3,5,7,8,7 which are seemingly random

Comment: thank you, my initial way just going about (4 * 5) + ( 5 * 8) = 60 and so the last was going to be 98 with (7 * 6) + (8 * 7) = 98 but that fails for value 32 as (3 * 4) + (7 * 5) fails...and other cases, I like your approach its practical but I was thinking there maybe more than 1 solution but for now it's going to be 98 :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would advise you (or the question setter) to avoid using standard mathematical symbols and notation in a decidedly non-standard way.

Better to write something like $(x,y)$ yields $z$.

Anyway your pattern seems to be: multiply both numbers together and add to the first number multiplied by its predecessor (one less).

Example for $6$ and $7$: $6 \times 7 + (6)(6-1)=72$

So the last one is $98$

There may be other solutions. An infinite number of possibilities in fact.

Comment: what other solution could there be tho is what I what to know besides 98? I have got 66, 80, but those need some more proofing to do..any idea